# Qt mac / carbon / cocoa : change titlebar color?

Tags: macos, cocoa, colors, macos-carbon, titlebar

I have a Qt app with a MainWindow; I would like to change the color of this titlebar. There is apparently no way of doing that by direct Qt calls; how could I manage to do that, even with carbon or cocoa calls?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_handle_events_in_the_titlebar_and_change_its_color_etc) you are looking for?

Comment: No. Toolbars would be upside of the custom titlebar, dockwidget would be eating the titlebar.